# failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.request.SolrRequestHandler

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr, lucene

I am using Tomcat 7, Solr 4.5.1 and Windows 7. My problem starts when I want to insert a file into solr:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.id=first" -F "file=@lesson1.pdf"
```

I am receiving an error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating Request Handler, solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.request.SolrRequestHandler
```

I've seen some answers here on SO and tried them - from copying some JAR's into my lib, to changing solrconfig.xml, but nothing helped. Any idea?

Before that error, I was receiving several others (missing classes) - so I've included in Tomcat/lib those jars:

```
apache-solr-cell-1.4.0.jar

solr-core-3.6.0.jar

solr-common-1.3.0.jar

tika-app-1.4.jar
```

Those errors went away, but this last error occured which I can't solve on my own. What should I do? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you mixing versions? You add solr core in version 3.6, but solr-cell in version 1.4 and solr-common in 1.3. And why don't you use the SOLR_HOME/lib folder for additional libraries?

Comment: I've switched for Solr 4.6 and Tomcat 8, but still receiving the same error. All file's versions are 4.6.